# Problem with restoring elements of Many-To-Many relationship

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I have created two classes `Musician` and `Band`, which have many to many relationship with class `Album`. I also use PostgreSQL database to reflect classes in relational database. I created a few `Musician`, `Band` and `Album` instances using Postman. I also created manually in postgres command line relationships in many to many tables (`album_band` and `album_musician`). Yet when I perform GET request on either `Band`, `Musician` or `Album` I don't get list of elements from corresponding relationship, only components of class itself (for example `Musician` contains fields `name`, `surname`, `dateOfBirth` and `List<Album> albums` (which is in many to many relationship with `Album` class) and I can only retrieve `name`, `surname` and `dateOfBirth` (`List<Album> albums` stays empty)). Below are classes and tables.

`Album` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="album")
public class Album {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Band.class, mappedBy = "albums")
    private List<Band> bands;
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Musician.class, mappedBy = "albums")
    private List<Musician> musicians;
    @Embedded
    @Column(name="duration")
    private Duration duration;
    @Column(name="dateofrelease")
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd/MM/yyyy", timezone="CET")
    private Date dateOfRelease;
    @Column(name="coverpath")
    private String coverPath;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public Duration getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
    public void setDuration(Duration duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
    public Date getDateOfRelease() {
        return dateOfRelease;
    }
    public void setDateOfRelease(Date dateOfRelease) {
        this.dateOfRelease = dateOfRelease;
    }
    public String getCoverPath() {
        return coverPath;
    }
    public void setCoverPath(String coverPath) {
        this.coverPath = coverPath;
    }
    public List<Band> getBands() {
        return bands;
    }
    public void setBands(List<Band> bands) {
        this.bands = bands;
    }
    public List<Musician> getMusicians() {
        return musicians;
    }
    public void setMusicians(List<Musician> musicians) {
        this.musicians = musicians;
    }
}
```

`Musician` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="musician")
public class Musician {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="surname")
    private String surname;
    @Column(name="dateofbirth")
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd/MM/yyyy", timezone="CET")
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "album_musician",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "album_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "musician_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Album> albums;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }
    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
    public List<Album> getAlbums() {
        return albums;
    }
    public void setAlbums(List<Album> albums) {
        this.albums = albums;
    }
}
```

`Band` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="band")
public class Band {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "album_band",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "album_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "band_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Album> albums;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Album> getAlbums() {
        return albums;
    }
    public void setAlbums(List<Album> albums) {
        this.albums = albums;
    }
}
```

`album` table:

```
                   Table "public.album"
    Column     |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id            | bigint  |           | not null | 
 title         | text    |           |          | 
 dateofrelease | date    |           |          | 
 coverpath     | text    |           |          | 
 hours         | integer |           |          | 
 minutes       | integer |           |          | 
 seconds       | integer |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "album_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "album_band" CONSTRAINT "album_band_album_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (album_id) REFERENCES album(id)
    TABLE "album_musician" CONSTRAINT "album_musician_album_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (album_id) REFERENCES album(id)
```

`musician` table:

```
                Table "public.musician"
   Column    |  Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------+--------+-----------+----------+---------
 id          | bigint |           | not null | 
 name        | text   |           |          | 
 surname     | text   |           |          | 
 dateofbirth | date   |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "musician_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "album_musician" CONSTRAINT "album_musician_musician_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (musician_id) REFERENCES musician(id)
```

`band` table:

```
               Table "public.band"
 Column |  Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+--------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | bigint |           | not null | 
 name   | text   |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "band_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "album_band" CONSTRAINT "album_band_band_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (band_id) REFERENCES band(id)
```

`album_musician` table:

```
             Table "public.album_musician"
   Column    |  Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------+--------+-----------+----------+---------
 album_id    | bigint |           | not null | 
 musician_id | bigint |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "album_musician_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (album_id, musician_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "album_musician_album_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (album_id) REFERENCES album(id)
    "album_musician_musician_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (musician_id) REFERENCES musician(id)
```

`album_band` table:

```
             Table "public.album_band"
  Column  |  Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------+--------+-----------+----------+---------
 album_id | bigint |           | not null | 
 band_id  | bigint |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "album_band_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (album_id, band_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "album_band_album_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (album_id) REFERENCES album(id)
    "album_band_band_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (band_id) REFERENCES band(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you created the join table ***album_band*** manually which is not required. Let Spring JPA creates the table automatically for you which improves the compatibility.

Comment: I deleted the tables (`album_band`, `album_musician`). Now Spring complains: `ERROR 11968 --- [nio-8090-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "album_band" does not exist` (same for `album_musician`)

Comment: add [at]Entity on album class if it fails. In general Spring should create your tables and dont have to handle anythind direct in your database. If you have same names for your table and class only annotaion [at]Entity can do the job (also you can remove [at]Table). And on last thing: you should configure your spring JPA to create automatically create-drop mysql dialect for you. For more info look at this post: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-jpa-hibernate-postgresql-restful-crud-api-example/.